# What is the best way to pass values from inputs through a JavaScript call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement the following functionality:

[image]

To create and recreate this table I have a button to with `onclick="submitEntries()"` which then calls an AJAX function

```
function submitEntries(){
    $.post("php/submitCompletedAndReload.php", {}, function(data){
        $('#response').html(data);
    });
}
```

'submitCompletedAndReload.php' has the following logic

1. ??? // This step needs to end with an array of objects storing the values in the rows
2. Post to the database all rows (in the form of objects) which are complete
3. store the incomplete rows (in the form of objects) in an array
4. reprint the incomplete rows

My Ajax response has this kind of html structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name='date'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name='time'>
    </td>
            ...more columns like this
  </tr>
            ...more rows like this
</table>
<button onclick="submitEntries()"></button>
```

I need to do is get all of the values from the inputs and pass them into the `onclick="submitEntries()"` in that last button, but I'm not sure how to go about that. **After the onclick event is triggered, how can I gather the inputs and pass them through to the JS call?**

Comment: You can use serialize: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: take a look at this example [http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/q01kL8fa/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/q01kL8fa/2/). once data submitted, process data in php and return errors or success upon completion.